# nullpointerexception while trying to retrieve from sqlite table in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to retrieve from a database a string array of product names.

```
package com.example.shopkart;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class giftpage extends Activity {
    TextView txtfinalbill;
    Button btnshowtotal;
    String name,mailid;
    datamanager dm;
    String[] products,quantity;
    int total=0,price1;
    int[] price;
    String pricelist;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.giftpage);
        dm=new datamanager(this);
        name=getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
        mailid=getIntent().getExtras().getString("mailid");
        txtfinalbill=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtfinalbill);
        btnshowtotal=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnshowtotal);
        btnshowtotal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                products=dm.getpurchaseproducts(mailid);
                quantity=dm.getpurchasequantity(mailid);

                for(int i=0;i<products.length;i++)
                {
                    price[i]=dm.getprice(products[i].toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," "+price[i],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Datamanager:

```
public int getprice(String product) {
    Cursor cu = DB1.rawQuery("SELECT PRICE from products where NAME='" + product + "'", null);
    cu.moveToFirst();
    if (!cu.isAfterLast()) {
        do {
            price = cu.getInt(0);
        }

        while (cu.moveToNext());
        cu.close();
    }
    return price;

}
```

The `dm.getprice` is the method which is giving trouble. I already got a `ResourceNotFoundException`, but that was solved by adding double quotes inside the toast.

LOGCAT:

```
04-21 05:08:37.655: E/AndroidRuntime(6764):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-21 05:42:08.095: E/AndroidRuntime(14727): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 05:42:08.095: E/AndroidRuntime(14727): Process: com.example.shopkart, PID: 14727
04-21 05:42:08.095: E/AndroidRuntime(14727): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-21 05:42:08.095: E/AndroidRuntime(14727):    at com.example.shopkart.giftpage$1.onClick(giftpage.java:44)
04-21 05:42:08.095: E/AndroidRuntime(14727):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
04-21 05:42:08.095: E/AndroidRuntime(14727):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
04-21 05:42:08.095: E/AndroidRuntime(14727):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-21 05:42:08.095: E/AndroidRuntime(14727):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-21 05:42:08.095: E/AndroidRuntime(14727):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-21 05:42:08.095: E/AndroidRuntime(14727):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
04-21 05:42:08.095: E/AndroidRuntime(14727):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 05:42:08.095: E/AndroidRuntime(14727):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-21 05:42:08.095: E/AndroidRuntime(14727):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
04-21 05:42:08.095: E/AndroidRuntime(14727):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
04-21 05:42:08.095: E/AndroidRuntime(14727):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your logcat stack trace.

Comment: have u opened your database... i think `dm.open()` is missing.

Comment: just print once and check..are you getting values into cursor obj..?
also price..?

Comment: where is "price" declared in your DataManager

Comment: price is declared at class level as an integer in datamanager.I dont think dm.open() is an issue as i am getting the other values withou any hitch.

Comment: still not working pls help!!

Comment: The soulution was price=new int[products.length]; FIXED!

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized your `price` array and attempting to assign to `price[i]` causes the NPE.

Add

```
price = new int[products.length];
```

before the `for` loop in `onClick()`.